# Is there any thing like BELARC ADVISOR

Tags: auditing

that will scan a whole domain and show the results in a web page of excel format

and ideally free (ish)

Would like something that doesn't need installing

Comment: What exactly would you expect to see in the results of such a scan? Information about the server? What about sub-domains, that could potentially run on a different server?

Comment: Also, your question isn't really about programming. Maybe you should ask on [Superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/) instead.

Comment: thanks Lars will post it there tbh got lost while traveling about the website

Comment: No problem. Just remember to clarify what you would expect as output from a scan, so that people can suggest the right tools. I thought about suggesting a pentesting tool (OWASP ZAP) but I'm not sure that would be the right tool for the job in this case.

Comment: Hi Lars belarc is like a machine aduting tool that prints out in a web page the machine hardware , software, security , patches etc (its not bad if your wanting to find that niggly bios version (you need to try it to see where I am coming from))   good for home use on old hardware